# Using if or mid and find in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Lets say column A1 contains 12769745. I want to extract 7697 from column A1 and want to use if statement. After the extract if it contains 7697, it should return one else return two. How to accomplish this in a single formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, this would go in `B1`

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(7697,A1,1)),1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(MID(A1,3,4)="7697",1,2)`

This is assuming that the the length will always be 8 digits.

You can adjust a more dynamic formula to be something like the below, though you will need to handle odd lengths by rounding up/down:

`=IF(MID(A1,LEN(A1)*0.25+1,LEN(A1)*0.5)="*7697*",1,2)`